# write_xlsx(all_trips, "trips.xlsx") Error: Error in libxlsxwriter: 'Worksheet row or column index out of range.'

Tags: r, writexl

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Language: R

I want to export the file to xlsx to used at Tableau Public but encounter the error

```
write_xlsx(all_trips, "trips.xlsx")
```

> Error: Error in libxlsxwriter: 'Worksheet row or column index out of
> range.'

Maybe the file too big?

```
str(all_trips) #See list of columns and data types (numeric, character, etc)
spec_tbl_df[,13] [3,574,524 x 13]
```

(S3:spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

Comment: please provide us with `dput(head(all_trips))`

Comment: sure, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sYPvzsWBQtjSEuNyuhOFAfNnY8cjccQLul1OjesyJUk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the the dataframe has 3 millions rows and Excel only supports 1 million rows (or specifically 1,048,576 rows), see [Excel's limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

Comment: thank you. but how to solve it?